# These two C++ codes look equivalent, why does only one compile?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++20

I think this code conforms to the C++20 standard and indeed compiles:

```cpp
consteval auto foo(int n){
    std::vector<int> v(n, 0);
    return v[0];
}
constexpr auto n = foo(5);
```

However if I slightly modify to use another constructor, Clang does not compile:

```cpp
consteval auto bar(int n){
    std::vector<int> v(n);
    return v[0];
}
constexpr auto m = bar(5);
```

This fails with:

```
...: error: call to consteval function 'bar' is not a constant expression
constexpr auto m = bar(5);
```

Both compile in GCC. Is this possibly just a bug?

I'm using Clang 14.0.6 (mingw winlibs), got this error, and found the same behavior in Clang 16.0.

Comment: Clang 15 [compiles fine](https://godbolt.org/z/zP5djG8br).

Comment: @康桓瑋 I omitted "-stdlib=libc++" argument, where can I find what does this do?

Comment: @wider93 It replaced which version of the C++ standard library you use with the compiler.  There is libc++ and libstdc++ as the two most common.  Changing it out will change if, say, a given constructor is constexpr.  Your standard library you are using is an incomplete implementation of C++20.

Comment: Here's a short reproduction: https://godbolt.org/z/3oP5qb57d. gcc's standard library (libstdc++) doesn't start object lifetimes, it just assigns. clang's (libc++) does, and clang is more picky about this. I suspect libstdc++ is technically wrong here, opened https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=109890